# Check avalara TLS 1.2 compliance

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, avalara

I need to check avalara TLS 1.2 compliance, But I didn't find any documentation

Could someone let me know the procedure to check compliance

Answer (score 1):

TLS is part of JRE security settings not related with hybris. You can check your JRE security configuration. Up to date JRE distributions supporting TLS 1.2 and old versions already disabled.

You can checkyour configuration in hac via groovy script. For example my web page supporting TLS 1.2 and 1.3.

```
URL url = new URL("http://mkysoft.com/ip.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
return org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is);
```

If you want to test other TLS/SSL/certificate/handshake options check https://badssl.com/ for alternative test endpoints.

Comment: Hi Mkysoft.. could you please let me know how to check JRE security configuration

Comment: Easy way is calling tls 1.2 endpoint in hac. I am adding example to the answer.